How to use the {titlesec} package to create this Chapter style?
I am writing a technical handbook and really like the chapter title below (from Life Technologies, thx). How can I use the titlesec package and fancyhdr package to achieve these?

Chapter style



For Unnumbered Chapter, just leave the box blank;
For Numbered Chapter, just like the picture.

Below is my try:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
    \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
    \setmonofont{Consolas}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{tcblue}{RGB}{25,64,122}
    \definecolor{tcgreen}{RGB}{19,142,61}
\usepackage[a4paper,
    left=25.4mm,
    right=25.4mm,
    top=25.4mm,
    bottom=25.4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}%{command}
    [block]%[shape]
    {\Huge\bfseries\scshape\color{tcblue}}%{format}
    {\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
        \colorbox{tcblue}{\parbox[c][2cm][c]{2cm}{%
                \centering\color{white}\fontsize{60}{80}\selectfont\thechapter}%
        }%
    }%{label}
    {1cm}%{sep}
    {}%{before}
    []%[after]
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,%
    allcolors=tcblue,
    ]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Product Information}\label{chap:product-information}
    \blindtext
\section{Purpose of the software}\label{sec:purpose-of-software}
    \blindtext
\section{About the data analysis}\label{sec:about-data-analysis}
    \blindtext
\end{document}

and the output is:

My problems are:

I don't know how to make the box (with the number) left while right-align the title;
I don't know how to put the toc of the chapter under the Chapter name. I tried to use minitoc package, but failed.

So, if someone can help me, it would be nice!

Welcome! Can you provide code for a minimal example so people can reproduce the output you have now? I assume you've tried something with those packages, so what problem did you encounter? (If you haven't tried anything, why do you want to use those particularly?) Note that it is impossible to answer with some code because the defaults depend on your class and any packages you're using to alter the page layout, for example. Please also explain why you want to avoid tikz so we know whether the reason also rules out e.g. pgf.

Also, note that there is a one-question-per-question format and that questions which just post images and ask other people to-do-this-complicated-thing-for-me tend to get closed.

Note, that there are already questions about chapter styles with boxed number. So you should be able to find a start point for this question. I've not searched for the other two questions, because you first should focus on one question and show what you've tried.

Sorry for my ambiguous question. I just edited my question. Thx!!! @cfr

Thank you! I tried to edit my question. @cabohah

These are still two questions. Please focus at one question per question. For the first: Have you tried \hfill at the argument you've commented with {before}? For the second: What have you exactly tried to show a chapter ToC (best show this in a new question again with MWE)? Have you noticed the note about incompatibility of titlesec and mintoc not only in the manual but also in the log file?

Moving the text of the chapter heading (for single-line headings) to the right while keeping the number left-aligned is relatively easy with \hfill in the last mandatory argument of \titleformat. To do it also for chapter headings with multiple lines, use \raggedleft\hfill.
Although the instructions for the minitoc package state that it is not compatible with titlesec and the log file also issues a corresponding warning, I get a chapter directory as soon as I load minitoc and insert the instructions \dominitoc, \tableofcontents and \minitoc according to the minitoc instructions.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
    \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
%    \setmonofont{Consolas}% commented, because I've not installed this font
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{tcblue}{RGB}{25,64,122}
    \definecolor{tcgreen}{RGB}{19,142,61}
\usepackage[a4paper,
    left=25.4mm,
    right=25.4mm,
    top=25.4mm,
    bottom=25.4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}%{command}
    [block]%[shape]
    {\Huge\bfseries\scshape\color{tcblue}}%{format}
    {\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
        \colorbox{tcblue}{\parbox[c][2cm][c]{2cm}{%
                \centering\color{white}\fontsize{60}{80}\selectfont\thechapter}%
        }%
    }%{label}
    {1cm}%{sep}
    {\raggedleft\hfill}%{before}
    []%[after]
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,%
    allcolors=tcblue,
    ]{hyperref}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Product Information}\label{chap:product-information}
\minitoc
    \blindtext
\section{Purpose of the software}\label{sec:purpose-of-software}
    \blindtext
\section{About the data analysis}\label{sec:about-data-analysis}
    \blindtext
\end{document}


Maybe the formatting of the chapter ToC is not exactly the one you want. In this case and if you fail to change it with the help of the minitoc manual, please ask a new question, because every question should only ask one question and the main topic of the asked question was IMHO, how to move the chapter title text to the right.

Thank you so much! I'll try to edit the chapter toc.

@FrankMosher Note that fancyhdr isn't relevant here because you aren't trying to change the running headers or footers at all. Personally, I would never have understood your question correctly before you edited it ;).

Thank you for your advice! I know the fancyhdr package isn't necessary here. I'll pay attention to the description of my question, and  focus at one question per question... Thanks again! @cfr
